# Two key pem for one instance amazon web service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I use a key pem ubuntu amazon in one aws instance and I want to add another key pem to access the same instance from another computer, but I want that the two key pems working. Is possible do it, one for me and another to my coworker? Two key pem with one instance?

I want to do it because only my computer have the permission to access the ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aws can apply one pem key when create a new instance.

You can manually set the second one on account ec2-user or any other accounts to let your colleague to login

Comment: what is the purpose of having multiple keys?